# Resize byte[] of Image

Tags: c#

After reading from file dialog I want to resize a picture. I have the done the following code. Now I want to resize the stream of picture. How do I do it?

```
Stream stream = (Stream)openFileDialog.File.OpenRead();
byte[] bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
```

Comment: http://programmerpayback.com/2010/01/21/use-silverlight-to-resize-images-and-increase-compression-before-uploading/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14316695/922198

Comment: 1St link solve my issue.thanks ken2K

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to declare a `byte[]`, to resize an image just use

```
Image image = Image.FromFile(fileName);
```

check [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501797/resize-image-proportionally-with-maxheight-and-maxwidth-constraints) to see how to scale the image aftewards

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
    public static Image ScaleImage(Image image, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
    {
        var ratioX = (double)maxWidth / image.Width;
        var ratioY = (double)maxHeight / image.Height;
        var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

        var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
        var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio);

        var newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
        Graphics.FromImage(newImage).DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
        return newImage;
    }
```

Usage

```
        Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);
        Image thumb = ScaleImage(img);
        stream.Close();
        stream.Dispose();
        stream = new MemoryStream();
        thumb.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an picturebox. I load an image, resizing and conveting to byte at last sending to sqllite. Maybe it can be hlepfıull to you Code is below.

```
private static byte[] byteResim = null;

    private void btnResimEkle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Resimdosyası seçiniz.";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Resim files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|Tüm dosyalar(*.*)|*.*";
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            string resimYol = openFileDialog1.FileName; // File name of the image

            picResim.Image = Image.FromFile(resimYol);// picResim is name of picturebox
            picResim.Image = YenidenBoyutlandir(new Bitmap(picResim.Image)); //this method resizing the image
            Image UyeResim = picResim.Image;   // and this four block converting to image to byte
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            UyeResim.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            byteResim = ms.ToArray();  // byteResim  variable format  Byte[]

        }
    }



    Image YenidenBoyutlandir(Image resim)// resizing image method 

    {
        Image yeniResim = new Bitmap(150, 156);
        using (Graphics abc = Graphics.FromImage((Bitmap)yeniResim))
        {
            abc.DrawImage(resim, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, 150, 156));
        }
        return yeniResim;
    }
```