# backgroundimagelayout hybrid between zoom and stretch

Tags: c#, winforms, image, user-interface

I am using Windows Forms and I'd like to place a background image in the upper left corner of my panel. I'd like to have the original `height:width-ratio` of the image preserved and the image should fill the control as much as possible.

`ImageLayout.Zoom` centers the image, which I don't like, but preserves the ratio which is good.
`ImageLayout.Stretch` puts the image in the upper left corner (in all other corners) as desired, but does not preserve the ratio.

So far I've used the approach of placing a picturebox into my panel that is resized based on its parent's size, when the parent is resized. I can achieve the desired effect, but I feel that there must be a nicer and built-in way.

Comment: You could use code like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6501997/2330053) by @AlexAza to create a properly resized image that can be used with the `None` layout.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was roughly doing anyways. The resizing itself hasn't be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
public class CustomPanel : Panel
{
    int x, y;
    public CustomPanel()
    {
        DoubleBuffered = true;
    }
    float scale;
    protected override void OnBackgroundImageChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        scale = (float)BackgroundImage.Width / BackgroundImage.Height;
        base.OnBackgroundImageChanged(e);
    }
    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if(BackgroundImage == null) base.OnPaintBackground(e);                        
        else {
         e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(BackColor), ClientRectangle);
         e.Graphics.DrawImage(BackgroundImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, x,y));
        }
    }
    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (scale > (float)Width / Height)
        {
            x = Width;
            y = (int)(Width / scale);
        }
        else
        {
            y = Height;
            x = (int)(Height * scale);
        }
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's it! I did not know about OnPaintBackground, thank you.