# unable to save images from picturebox to datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview

I've seen [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12850/Capturing-the-Desktop-Screen-with-the-Mouse-Cursor) tutorial on how to capture the screen with cursor.
Now I added a timer and datagridview and I want to save every capture in the datagridview. Here is what I did:

```
private void Display(Bitmap desktop)
{
    Graphics g;
    Rectangle r;
    if (desktop != null)
    {
        r = new Rectangle(0, 0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
        g = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        g.DrawImage(desktop, r);
        g.Flush();

            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height, g);

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(bmp);
    }
}
```

But all I get is white images like this:

[image]

I can't reach the point where I can save what appear on `picturebox` and add it to the `datagridview`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using CreateGraphics is a temporary drawing on the screen, so the image isn't getting transferred to the bitmap.

Try drawing directly instead:

```
private void Display(Bitmap desktop) {
  if (desktop != null) {
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width, 
                            pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)) {
      g.DrawImage(desktop, Point.Empty);
    }
    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(bmp);
  }
}
```

Comment: well it did save the capture in the `datagridview`, but how to view it in `picturebox` every time before it added to the datagridview

Comment: @MagedEWilliam Updated the post with the PictureBox Image property showing the same bitmap.

Comment: Nice, but how to make it `jepg` with half the resulotion

Comment: @MagedEWilliam That sounds like a different question.  Not sure what `half the resolution` means, but you can just do a `bmp.Save(filename, ImageFormat.Jpeg);`

Comment: oh, insted of 1366x768, i need to be 683, 384

Comment: See [Resize image proportionally with MaxHeight and MaxWidth constraints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501797/resize-image-proportionally-with-maxheight-and-maxwidth-constraints)