# Adjust images with window C#

Tags: c#, image

So, I'm basically new using WinForms in Visual Studio 2017
Probably this questions are already answered but I can't find how to do it.

I just want to make the window bigger, but the images adjusting while I do it, any advise?
I've doing this all with the Menu and Toolbox, so basically I don't have any code to show

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

Edit: 
I found a way to adjust the image but it needs to be full screen with PictureBox and activate 'Parent Container', but it's not what I need

Comment: pictureBox.Size = this.Size;

Comment: Possible duplicate of [resizing pictureBox proportionally to Form resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23982033/resizing-picturebox-proportionally-to-form-resizing)

Comment: Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501797/resize-image-proportionally-with-maxheight-and-maxwidth-constraints/6501997#6501997)