# How to place maximum images in a blank Bitmap based on column/row input & margin variables and preserving aspect ratio of images

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

This might be a tricky question.

I will just cut to the chase.
First i make a blank Bitmap image:

```
Bitmap MasterImage = new Bitmap(PageSize.Width, PageSize.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(MasterImage);
```

Afterwards:
I get a parameter of how much images i want to place in the Blank Bitmap (page) based on columns and rows:

```
int numOfColumns=2; //(could be any value)
int numOfRows=4;
```

So we should get something like this:

[image]

I also get a parameter if i have some margin at top image and left image:

```
int PagetopMargin=0; //(could be any value)
int PageLeftMargin=0;
```

Than i have a variable called: `imagesPath` which is type of `List<String>` it contains full path of images.

Now i loop through images:

```
  while (imagesPath.Count > 0)
   {
      Image image = Image.FromFile(imagesPath[0]);
    //Logic comes here. 
    //after finishing processing and drawing images in Bitmap i remove image from list
      imagesPath.RemoveAt(0);
    }
```

What i am trying to achieve is how to place maximum images in that Bitmap page based on column/row and margin variables and preserving aspect ratio of images. (so images wont get distorted). if some images are left behind, its okey, i will continue next blank Bitmap to place them. just need to fill the Bitmap blank image to the full.

Comment: OK, so what is the question? How to scale an image to fit in a Rectangle ? There is a DrawImage overload that does just that. (The one with two Rectangles).

Comment: How do i scale the images (its a list of images) to fit the Rectangle based on the parameters and preserving images aspect ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a function to fit a rectangle into another, either centered or uncentered (aligned top-left):

```
Rectangle FitToBox(Rectangle scr, Rectangle dest, bool centered)
{
    var ratioX = (double)dest.Width / scr.Width;
    var ratioY = (double)dest.Height / scr.Height;
    var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

    var newWidth = (int)(scr.Width * ratio);
    var newHeight = (int)(scr.Height * ratio);

    if (!centered)
        return new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
    else
        return new Rectangle((dest.Width - newWidth) / 2, 
                             (dest.Height - newHeight) / 2, newWidth, newHeight);
}
```

Its basic math is taken form [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501797/resize-image-proportionally-with-maxheight-and-maxwidth-constraints).

Here is a test bed, centered and uncentered using different random values:

[image][image]

```
Random rnd = new Random();

int cols = rnd.Next(3) + 2;
int rows = rnd.Next(4) + 3;

int w = pan_dest.Width / cols;
int h = pan_dest.Height / rows;
using (Graphics G = pan_dest.CreateGraphics())
{
    G.Clear(Color.White);
    for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++)
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
        {
            Rectangle rDest = new Rectangle(c * w, r * h, w, h);
            Rectangle rSrc = new Rectangle(0, 0, rnd.Next(200) + 10, rnd.Next(200) + 10);
            Rectangle rResult = FitToBox(rSrc, rDest, checkBox1.Checked);
            Rectangle rDestPlaced = new Rectangle(c * w + (int)rResult.X, 
                                        r * h + rResult.Y, rResult.Width, rResult.Height);

            using (Pen pen2 = new Pen(Color.SlateGray, 4f))
                G.DrawRectangle(pen2, Rectangle.Round(rDest));
            G.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, rDestPlaced);
            G.FillEllipse(Brushes.LightPink, rDestPlaced);
        }
}
```

You would then draw your images like this:

```
  G.DrawImage(someImageimg, rDestPlaced, rSrc, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

This maximizes the image **sizes**, not the **number** of images you can fit on a page, as specified in your comment. For the latter you should look into something like  [2-dimensional packing](http://cgi.csc.liv.ac.uk/~epa/surveyhtml.html)..

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. very interesting concept and smart thinking! I still have some issues that i will explain in my question as soon as i grasp them after testing..

Comment: I did manage to use your technique introduced with a small adjustment..I wanted that  images will stick to one another so i just played a bit with where to place the next image location parameters.  thanks !